# Move selected text to the left or right in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, is there any command currently to move the selected text to the left or right?

I'm not talking about indentation btw.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This feature has been implemented by [a pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/6887) some time ago.

To use it you need to bind the `editor.action.moveCarretLeftAction` and `editor.action.moveCarretRightAction` actions in the keyboard shortcuts editor.

[image: Animation showing how the solution works]

Comment: I found using `Ctrl` + `Shift` + (`LeftArrow` || `RightArrow`) convenient. And for the **When**, use `editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly`

Comment: @Ismail not a good one in my opinion b/c that key combination already does text selection in chunks.

Comment: Yeah I think also that its not good. Better is to use just default `alt+left` with `"when": "editorFocus && (editorHasSelection || editorHasMultipleSelections "` .
Complete messed up code in comment:
```{
        "key": "alt+left",
        "command": "editor.action.moveCarretLeftAction",
        "when": "editorFocus && (editorHasSelection || editorHasMultipleSelections "
    }
```

Comment: VSCode will support parentheses soon ([#174471](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/174471)), for now this works: `editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && editorHasSelection || editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && editorHasMultipleSelections`

Comment: can we move the selection to the end of line or beginning.. not just one char after another..

Answer (score 60):

#### Moving blocks of text

A workaround for moving a block of text of just one space is to use the "column selection" feature of Visual Studio. here the detailed instruction:

- move the cursor at the upper left corner of the block of text you want to shift;
- click with the mouse holding down shift + alt, on the down left corner of the block of text you want to shift;
- now you could insert as many spaces as you want.

If you need more info on Block Selection in Visual Studio you could easily find information on the official documentation or here: [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/block-selection) 
Pay attention in the link the shortcut is wrong, at least for me.

---

#### Indentation

For moving the text right and left you can use TAB key:

- TAB move the selected text right
- SHIFT + TAB move the selected text left

Comment: Thank you for the input but I was not talking about indentation but actually shifting the words one character/word to the left/right.

Comment: I have added a trick in my previous post, now should answer your question. Regards.

Comment: Great. Helpful :)

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + ALT if you want to create vertical line to move multiple rows at once

Answer (score 13):

Ok, so these answers didn't really help me as I am a beginner, here is what I did.

1. Goto `File->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts`.
2. Search `Move Carret Left` and `Move Carret Right` and add your desired keys combinations. (2022 update: If searching these terms don't work search the term `carret`.)
3. You are done, now test it by selecting a test and firing the key combinations.

Comment: Searching for `Move carret...` doesn't work anymore (2022) but just searching for `carret` does.

Answer (score 5):

Add/edit keyboard shortcut:

[image]

1. Keyboard shortcuts settings - ctrl+k, ctrl+s
2. Search "Move Selected Text Left" or "Move Selected Text Right"
3. Double click -  to add/edit "Key binding"
4. ctrl+k, ctrl+E - to add/edit "When" condition

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to suggestions here I created custom key binding (ctrl+shift+p -> shortcut json) accordingly:

```json
    {
        "key": "alt+left",
        "command": "editor.action.moveCarretLeftAction",
        "when": "editorFocus && editorHasSelection || editorHasMultipleSelections "
    },
    {
        "key": "alt+right",
        "command": "editor.action.moveCarretRightAction",
        "when": "editorFocus && editorHasSelection || editorHasMultipleSelections"
    }
```

This "when" functionality is nice, ref [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-contexts)

Hmm, strange that `"when": "editorFocus && (editorHasSelection || editorHasMultipleSelections)"` doesn't work.. I forgot to write ending ")" and it worked, added it while writing this answer and it stopped functioning.. hm,  maybe somebody can point out what is wrong.

Comment: VSCode will support parentheses soon ([#174471](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/174471)), for now this works: `editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && editorHasSelection || editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && editorHasMultipleSelections`

Answer (score 2):

**I have add this feature in my vs code using following steps.**

**Usage** : *By using this key bind feature we can move selected text move left/right using keyboard shortcut*.

[Move selection texts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUde0.png)

**Steps to implement this** -->

Open VS code.

Press ctrl + p

Press > and search --> Open keyboard shortcuts (JSON)

Filename : keybindings.json

Add this following code as it is.

Restart your vs code once.

```
{
    "key": "alt+shift+left",
    "command": "editor.action.moveCarretLeftAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
{
    "key": "alt+shift+right",
    "command": "editor.action.moveCarretRightAction",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
```

Comment: Pressing `alt` and `shift` at the same time is not a possible key binding at least in Linux.