# Can I move selected text left and right in visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

I'm hoping this question doesn't get deemed as a duplicate, as my question pertains to Visual Studio 2019. Not VS Code. - [Move selected text to the left or right in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48992252/move-selected-text-to-the-left-or-right-in-visual-studio-code)

Is there a key binding I can use that will allow me to move any selected text in a line, left and right? Additionally to that, would it also be possible to send selected text to the start or end of a line (like Home and End key does to the cursor)

If this is possible, it would be a very handy shortcut for me to make use of. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently I use: Ctrl + X, End, Ctrl + V to achieve this. While this is okay. If I could do all that in one shortcut, that would be much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

In VS-2022, first highlight the lines you want to move, then...

- to move to the right, press the TAB key. (note, that you're highlighting only 1 row, then ensure that you highlight the *entire* row)
- to move to the left, hold SHIFT key, then (while still holding SHIFT)
  press TAB key. (now release SHIFT)